# Selenium Entering Username and Password in Alert box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to input a username and password into an alert box using selenium and Java. I'm not sure if this is an alert box or something else, but I've attached a screenshot for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU8Z7.png)

I have tried switching to the alertbox and sending keys ("username" + Keys.TAB + "password") and selenium couldn't find the alertbox. any information helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the login and the password within the URL: `https://login:password@somepage.com`

```py
driver.get("https://foo:bar@httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar")
```

Perhaps you'll need to reload the page.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! That ended up working

Comment: In SO, you thank someone by accepting their answer if it resolved the issue.